# is RxJava framework lock-free & wait-free?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, rx-java

I am interested to know if RxJava framework is lock-free and wait-free like Lmax Disruptor? Does it use techniques like  cache line padding to avoid false sharing for better performance?

Comment: it is an interesting question, not sure why it has been downvoted!

Comment: RxJava as whole does not deal with threading — individual Schedulers do. If you use RxJava with lock-free Scheduler, it will probably be (mostly) lock-free. I doubt, that there are any wait-free schedulers (AFAIK, Disruptor is not wait free, it still needs to wait/busy-loop when retrieving tasks).

Answer (score 0):

It does use padding to minimize false sharing, but it definitely uses queues (home grown) and locks, countdownlatch in some places like .merge/.flatmap etc...

I don't think any decent framework would dare use busy-wait spinning under the hood without telling it's user base. It would be excruciatingly expensive on CPU.